# Update values inside cell after NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableview and I link it to core data using NSFetchedResultsController. I have a method `updateCellAtIndexPath`, that I am using to update cell text label. I call this method from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`. That works fine.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)updateCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TripCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];    
    Trip *trip = [_controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
    cell.textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,trip.name ];        
    return cell;
}
```

When I update core data object I receive NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate and I call `updateCellAtIndexPath`. The problem is that the cell text label is not updated correctly to actual value. I think the cell is not reloaded, because everything works if I change `updateCellAtIndexPath` to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

```
-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    switch (type){  
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
           // works [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; 
           // not works [self updateCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But when I read the documentation for `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, it says that I should not use this method if I want just to update values:

> Call this method if you want to alert the user that the value of a
>   cell is changing. If, however, notifying the user is not
>   important—that is, you just want to change the value that a cell is
>   displaying—you can get the cell for a particular row and set its new
>   value.

Why then I can not update cell text label using just `updateCellAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updateCellAtIndexPath:` method *creates a new cell* instead of updating the existing one.
That is OK if called from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but not when called from the FRC
delegate methods.

It should work if you implement and use the "standard"

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

which you can find e.g. when creating a new app using the (Master-Detail + Core Data)
template in Xcode.

Comment: Hello Martin,I have a Cell that is created with different XIB and classes and all inheriting the base class MessageCell with sub classes Cells as incoming , outgoing, media, audio, location cells : Message cell.